# Subclassing dataframe to store modified strings

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to subclass a dataframe such that when I do say

```
df.loc[index,column] = 'green'
```

the corresponding value specified by [index,column] takes on the value

```
'background-color: green'
```

as an example.

Basically I have a lot of custom formatting to do to my dataframes before I send them to excel and since the styler requires storing the styles in dataframes with these strings, I want to create a subclassed dataframe for the styles I am applying to make storing them easier.

I hope my explanation makes sense.

The conditional formatting is no good for me, as a lot of the colors I am getting are being pulled from existing html tables that I have to do a lot of web-scraping to obtain.

Edit: The way the pandas styler object works is that you take a function, which takes the df you wish to style, as an input, and it returns with another dataframe which same index and columns with the style options.

For example I have dataframe

```
df

              A  B  C   D
first second             
A1    2       1  3  2   4
A2    2       5  2  2   3
A3    1       3  4  7   6
A4    4       4  3  3  12
A5    6       2  4  4   7
```

for the values in df that equal two, I want to make their background color blue when exporting this df to excel.

So I'll make a function

```
def make_2_blue(df):
   background_color = pd.DataFrame('',columns=df.columns,index=df.index)   
   background_color[df == 2] = 'background-color: blue'
   return
```

Then when I want to export this to excel I'd do

```
df.styler.apply(make_2_blue,axis=None).to_excel('blah.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
```

Now in my example I am webscraping html to get the individual cells background color.

What I want to do is subclass a dataframe to make applying these formats easier.

Essentially I would like create some styler-dataframe where I specify the style and then I when I access the individual values in the df it will take in my string and apply the desired formatting.

So lets say I make a background-color dataframe class. I'll make an instance of it called `background_color_df`.

```
background_color_df = pd.DataFrame('',index=df.index,columns=df.columns)
>>> background_color_df
                               A                   B                   C  \
first second
A1    2       background-color:   background-color:   background-color:
A2    2       background-color:   background-color:   background-color:
A3    1       background-color:   background-color:   background-color:
A4    4       background-color:   background-color:   background-color:
A5    6       background-color:   background-color:   background-color:
                               D
first second
A1    2       background-color:
A2    2       background-color:
A3    1       background-color:
A4    4       background-color:
A5    6       background-color:
```

Now I go to assign the color blue at a specific index and column

```
background_color_df.loc['A1','A'] = 'blue'
background_color_df
                                   A                   B                   C  \
first second
A1    2       background-color: blue  background-color:   background-color:
A2    2           background-color:   background-color:   background-color:
A3    1           background-color:   background-color:   background-color:
A4    4           background-color:   background-color:   background-color:
A5    6           background-color:   background-color:   background-color:

                               D
first second
A1    2       background-color:
A2    2       background-color:
A3    1       background-color:
A4    4       background-color:
A5    6       background-color:
```

Comment: I kind of understand but not clear what you need, can you please add more details and a sample of the code you tried or expected the result to help you better with this.

Comment: Can you explain, what `'background-color'` corresponds to? should it be concatenated from the column name and index name in `df.loc[index,column] = 'green'`?

Comment: @SundeepPidugu I added a better explanation

Comment: @jottbe I added a better explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right, you have data like this:

```
             color   foo
background   green   bar
foreground   red     baz
```

That is, a dataframe with attributes for some kind of category like foreground and background and you need them combined like:

```
             color                     foo
background   background-color: green   background-foo: bar
foreground   foreground-color: red     foreground-foo: baz
```

Please ignore the column names and index names here, as you could change them easily.

If that is, what you need, you don't need to subclass `DataFrame`, which will surely be a lot of work. You could just postprocess your dataframe so it looks like what you want. E.g. by doing:

```
# example data
df= pd.DataFrame({'color': ['green', 'red'], 'foo': ['bar', 'baz']}, index=['background', 'foreground'])

columns_to_transform= ['color', 'foo']  # maybe even: df.columns if you need to transform all columns
for col in columns_to_transform:
    df[col]= df.index + '-' + col + ': ' + df[col]
```